# Color Detection And Comaparision In Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, color-detection

I am trying to figure out whether a particular color exists in an image or not? I want to write a Python code to compare the given color value with a color from the certain location coordinates of the image. I already tried to get a solution with Segmentation of Image on Color space, but I can not make it.

I am using Python "OpenCV".

```
I want to make program like:

given_color = Blue (Color Values)
if Blue == Color_values_detected_from_image:
    print("Blue Color is present at your given area")
else:
    print("Given Color Not Found")
```

Could you please advise me on where should I start?

I am expecting that if I am giving coordinates of rectangle in certain area of image then it should be compared with my given color values.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by simple pixel-wise comparison and NumPy's [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) method.

Let's have a look at the following code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read input image
img = cv2.imread('images/colors.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow('img', img)

# Region of interest (x1, x2, y1, y2)
roi = (200, 700, 0, 100)
imgRoi = img[roi[2]:roi[3], roi[0]:roi[1]]
cv2.imshow('imgRoi', imgRoi)

# Color of interest [B, G, R]
coi = [0, 255, 0]

# Compare each pixel with color; logical AND over all colors (axis=2)
cmp = np.all(imgRoi == coi, axis=2)

# From here, do whatever you like with this information...

# For example, show mask where color of interest was found
out = np.zeros((imgRoi.shape[0], imgRoi.shape[1], 1), np.uint8)
out[cmp] = 255
cv2.imshow('out', out)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The input image looks like this:

[image: Input]

The region of interest (ROI) looks like this:

[image: ROI]

As an exemplary output, here's the mask where the color of interest `#00ff00` was found:

[image: Mask]

Hope that helps!

P.S. The Python/NumPy masters may please suggest a more elegant way to "translate" the two points `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)` to the indices `x1:x2`, `y1:y2`. Right now, this notation looks quite cumbersome...

Comment: It is working somewhat but the main problem is I want to get status of traffic signal and after that I want to do another process with the status results.
Another one is if the is small differences in color? Like various shades of color OR ROI contains different shades in that.

Comment: @AnantPatankar Unfortunately, your initial question had a (very) limited problem statement. 1) You can encapsulate my approach in some function returning some boolean indicating, whether the color has been found in the ROI or not. This work is left to you. 2) Check OpenCV's [`inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) method. The approach is basically the same. For the future, when asking questions on StackOverflow, please formulate the actual problem you want to solve, not just a limited part of it to prevent half-baked answers.